# Переход на сайт с помощью кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Всем привет! Есть код с формой регистрации, в конце есть кнопка, если все условия выполнены верно нужно перейти на сайт. Хочу узнать как задать кнопке условия чтобы после регистрации она перекидывала на сайт.

Моя кнопка была реализована с помощью input type="submit" , пробовал сделать событие onClick, но если делать так, то оно не проверят мои условия для имени, пола и даты. А просто переходит на новую страницу по нажатию. А мне нужно чтобы если пользователь ввел все правильно, только тогда при нажатии переходить на сайт. Заранее спасибо за ответ и помощь

Вот мой код

```js
var form = document.getElementById('form'); //получаю форму по айди

        form.addEventListener('submit',function(e){ // ставлю на форму слушатель событий ра екшен submit(когба будет нажата кнопка с типом submit в форме), вторым аргументом идёт функция что сработает если произойдёт событие, в ней переменая e(название может быть любое), в которой всякие штуки для обраюотки события
            valid(form);//вызываю ту фукнции и передаю в неё форму
            noChecked(form);
            //noDate(form);
            e.preventDefault();//отменяю стандартное поведение события submit(обновление страници)
        })
        
        // Проверка на нажатие радио кнопок
        function noChecked(form) {
            if (document.getElementById('women').checked || document.getElementById('men').checked) {
                //
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('forStatus').style.display = 'inline-flex';
            }
        }

        function valid (form) {
            
            var name = form.name.value; 
            
            
            var dateStr = document.getElementById("date").value;

            // Создание объекта Date из даты введённой пользователем
            // и текущего времени
            var date = new Date(dateStr), now = new Date();

            // "Грубое" вычисление возраста и разницы между месяцами и днями
            var age = now.getYear() - date.getYear(),
            monthDiff = now.getMonth() - date.getMonth(),
            dayDiff = now.getDate() - date.getDate();
            // проверяем наступил ли день рождения в текущем году
            // и если ещё не наступил, то уменьшаем возраст
            if(monthDiff < 0 || (monthDiff === 0 && dayDiff < 0)) {
                age--;
            }
    
            
            
            if (name == "" || name==" ") {
               
                document.getElementById('forName').style.display = 'block';
            
            }
            
            
            
            // Если мужчина < 21
            else if (document.getElementById('men').checked && age < 21) {
                document.getElementById('forDate').style.display = 'inline-flex';
            }
            
            // Если женщина < 18
            else if (document.getElementById('women').checked && age < 18) {
               // alert('Вы мужчина!Error!'); 
                document.getElementById('forDate').style.display = 'inline-flex';
            }
                
            //
            //
            else if (document.getElementById('women').checked) {
                alert('Вы женщина!');
            }
            
            
                
            //
            //
            
        }
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
body {
    background-image: url(img/reg_bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: cover;
}
form {
    background: #fff;
    display: block;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 30vh 0 0 35%;
    height: 35vh;
}
form h1 span {
    color: #ff8b38;
}

.input_name input { /* Для имени */
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff8b38;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.input_name {
    margin: 3% 0 0 25%;
}
.input_status {
    margin: 2% 0 0 27%;
}
.input_status #men {
    
}
.input_date {
    margin-left: 25%;
}
.input_date input { /* Для даты */
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff8b38;
    outline: none;
}
.input_name, .input_status, .input_date { /* Для имени, пола и даты */
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
#forName, #forStatus, #forDate { /* Для имени, пола и даты */
    display: none;
    color: red;
}







/* Для кнопки */

#myButton {
    background-color: rgba(255,139,56,0.9);
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #d16c21;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 2% 0%;
    margin: 2% 0 0 25%;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#myButton:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgba(255,139,56,0.8);
    transition: 0.2s;
    border: 2px solid #ff8b21;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form registration on JavaScript</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
    
    
    
    
    <form action="index1" method="post" name="form" id="form">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;">Form Reg on <span>J</span>ava<span>S</span>cript</h1>
        <div class="input_name">
            
            <input class="for_name" type="text" placeholder="Введите своё имя" id="name">
            
            <div class="for_name" id="forName">
                <p style="margin: 0;"><img src="img/red-cross.png" alt="Red cross" style="margin-top: 2.5px;" title="Вы не ввели имя"></p>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
        
        <br><br>
        
        <div class="input_status">
            
            <input type="radio" id="men" name="status" value="men">
            <label for="men" style="margin: 0 10px 0 5px">Мужской</label>
            <input type="radio" id="women" name="status" value="women">
            <label for="women" style="margin: 0 10px 0 5px;">Женский</label>
            
            <div class="for_status" id="forStatus">
                <p style="margin: 0;"><img src="img/red-cross.png" alt="Red cross" style="margin-top: 2.5px;" title="Вы не ввели пол"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        <br><br>
        
        
        
        <div class="input_date">
            
            <input type="date" id="date" style="width: 175px;">
            
            <div class="for_date" id="forDate">
                <p style="margin: 0;"><img src="img/red-cross.png" alt="Red Cross" style="margin-top: 2.5px;" title="Вы слишком молоды для этого сайта"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
   
        
        
        
        <br><br>
        

        
        <input type="submit" value="Войти" name="submit" id="myButton"/> 
        
        
    </form>
    
    
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Для отмены в обработчике события формы `submit` верните `false`: 
`if(formIsValid() === false) return false;`

Comment: Ничего не понял, слишком сложны слова)

Comment: Очень много кода, который никто читать не будет, но я так понял, что ты в нём делаешь проверки некие. Если проверки прошли, просто внутри функции после всего этого скажи `window.location.href = 'url'` И всё. Тебя перекинет на нужный урл. Если об этом речь.

Comment: Я должен создать переменную formisValid и занести в неё значение true, а дальше написать ваше условие?

Comment: Видел этот способ, но с ним если его вставить то все мои условия игнорируются  и выполняется только это.

Comment: Типо мне должна выдаваться ошибка если хотя бы одно условие не выполнено. А тут просто переход не другой сайт

Comment: @Lisenok сервак на пыхе написан?

Comment: Нет, это просто как для саморазвития делаю, вот не могу найти способ. Думал взять функцию с условиями и написать if (validate (form) == true ){
        return window.location.href = 'URL';
    } Но так не работает(

Comment: @Lisenok не return window.blablabla, а просто window.location.href = 'нужный урл'. Это команда. Она выполняется просто. Ничего не возвращает. Тут нужно смотреть как сервер реализован. Если ему нужен сабмит, то сабмит, но я на своей короткой практике не встречал такого. Просто аяксом шлю или пост, или гет, или что там рест говорит слать, и жду респонс. Если серваку надо x-www-form-urlencoded, то опять же, упаковываю это всё в new FormData() и просто отправляю объект. Короче, нужно понимать, что ждёт сервер.

Comment: Нет. Создайте функцию, которая будет проверять корректность заполнения полей формы: если всё ОК, то функция возвращает `true`, в противном случае `false`. Далее Вы выполняете эту функцию и если функция возвратила `false`, то Вы можете, к примеру, выводить сообщение об ошибке и возвращать `false` из функции-обработчика. В этом случае форма отправлена не будет. 
P.S.: не поймите меня не правильно, но если Вы сталкиваетесь с таким непониманием, то может быть Вам стоит что-то по-проще попробовать?

Comment: Это лабораторная работа на следующий год по курсу веб-программирование. Первые две лабы это обычная верстка макетов 2001 года :D Ту что я делаю сейчас нужно реализовать на JS, следующую на php